# Failed Slackware Setup - Internet Permanently Broken

Tags: linux, windows, networking, wireless-networking, slackware

I am new to Linux. I tried to install Slackware 14 on a fresh partition, with the rest of the HD as free space, except for the small "Dell" partition that seems to be necessary.

I got Slackware working more or less, but I couldn't figure out how to connect to the internet. I have a wireless network running from my OTHER computer, which is used as a virtual router.

Apparently there was no Network Manager available or installed on Slackware. I tried adding the Network Manager widget to the desktop, as was recommended, but it said there was no Network Manager program available for it to reference.

I followed some steps I found online to download Wicd, hoping that it could solve my internet woes. As root, I set some variables equal to "" (blank). I forget what they were, but some online forum member said that you had to set them blank to get Wicd to work. Then I tried to install Wicd from my Slackware DVD, but no matter what i tried, i couldn't get Wicd to install.

My internet still didn't work, so I just decided to set up Windows 7 as a dual-boot and get on the internet that way. But Windows couldn't find any networks either. It showed that no wireless networks were available (there are plenty in my area), and none of Microsoft's troubleshooters worked.

So then I decided to delete my Linux and Windows partitions, reinstall Windows, and try again. Using Slackware's partition manager, I deleted my Windows and Linux partitions, leaving only the Dell partition (a few MB i think) and free space. I booted like this just to make sure everything was wiped, and there was some looping text on the screen, but nothing further happened.

Then I reinstalled Windows 7 from DVD, but STILL no networks could be found.

What have I done??? Will I ever be able to access the internet again?

Thanks

Comment: You are new to Linux and you tried to install *Slackware*?

Comment: Slackware is a great distro to start with, given some dedication and time to read the handbook.

Comment: You said you had a wireless network running from your other computer. Is that still working - i.e. able to accept connections and connect to the internet? Have you cycled it to clear out its DHCP cache and any leftover stale connection data?

Comment: Also, to follow up on @thkala's comment - I'd suggest starting out with a much more user-friendly distro like [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/). It's designed with new Linux users in mind, and in my experience is a lot easier to get working "out of the box." Not that I'm hating on Slackware (I started out with it in the early-mid 90s), it's just geared towards more experienced users...